# How to use the result of FBSDKGraphRequest Outside the Block

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, objective-c-blocks, fbsdk

I am designing an application which uses Facebook to display the feeds in a table view ..so in order to get the result of the feeds i have called a method **FBSDKGraphRequest** but I do not know how to retrieve the values of the results from **FBSDKGraphRequest** outside since they are located in a completion block.I want to display the name and message in the table view....

The code illustration is below:-

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]initWithGraphPath:Path parameters:@{ @"fields": @"feed{from,message,created_time}",} tokenString:accessToken version:FBSDK_TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

    if(error)
        NSLog(@"No Data");

    else {
       FeedCount = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:result];
       NSDictionary*feed = [FeedCount objectForKey:@"feed"];
       NSArray*array1 = [feed objectForKey:@"data"];
       NSArray*array3 = [array1 valueForKey:@"from"];
       NSLog(@"Data:%@",array3); ---------------> **Displaying Data**
         }
   }];
NSLog(@"FeedCount:%@",FeedCount);----------------->**Showing Null**
```

Any help will be Appreciated

Comment: You can get data in dictionary like as : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30439246/facebook-graph-object-entity-parsing-sdk-4-in-swift/30439458#30439458

Comment: i have created a dictionary as FeedCount and assigned a dictionary which is result to it!! Am able to display data with in the block but not outside the block but i want the whole data to use outside!!

Comment: Block is asynchronous you can only get data after response came. `FeedCount` is null until the block is in process. put that line of `NSLog` inside your block you will get the result. @hariteja

Comment: Yeah!! that's right @Ashish..I got the data of the result by putting NSLOG in the block but i want to use the data outside Where i want to Use the feeds to display in table View...

Comment: Now you have data call the method to update the data in view. It's very simple.

Answer (score 0):

To get the result of dictionary from fbsdk please declare variable  as `__block NSDictionary *json;`

Then assign this inside block like,

```
json =[FeedCount objectForKey:@"feed"];
```

Did you try this like,

```
__block NSDictionary *json;

FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]initWithGraphPath:Path parameters:@{ @"fields": @"feed{from,message,created_time}",} tokenString:accessToken version:FBSDK_TARGET_PLATFORM_VERSION HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

    if(error)
        NSLog(@"No Data");

    else {
       FeedCount = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:result];
       json = [FeedCount objectForKey:@"feed"];
       NSArray*array1 = [feed objectForKey:@"data"];
       NSArray*array3 = [array1 valueForKey:@"from"];
       NSLog(@"Data:%@",array3); ---------------> **Displaying Data**
         }
   }];
NSLog(@"json:%@",json);
```

Comment: I am getting Null even by declaring a variable as __block NSDictionary but able to retrieve inside the block!!

Comment: Now im update it check it out now.. I have the block of afnetwork response.. It works for me

Comment: If i use Json in the table view Delegate methods it returning null value  for NSLOG(json:%@,json)

Comment: please note my updated answer. check it out with this. Can you please show the result of your response from graphAPI?

Comment: json:{
    data =     (
                {
            "created_time" = "2015-12-23T08:25:23+0000";
            from =             {
                id = 976135482448053;
                name = "Hariteja Joshi";
            };
            id = "17045789536545339_1729391097292706";
            message = hiiii;
        },

Comment: The above data which am able to get by placing NSLOG inside the block but getting null outside!!

Comment: i found one link related to this but the solution was not quite useful but there  must be a way to get the results outside the block http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30301034/how-to-retrieve-the-results-of-fbsdkgraphrequest-to-use-outside

Comment: I too don't know my friend.. I used more than one blocks in my code. All it works on my project. Please keep the updated code .. Study on that, You can budddy